# How to add an "index" column to a SQLite view?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a view where order matters and I'd like an "index" column on it (counting 1, 2, 3 etc), so I can SELECT that column and get the places that the matched rows fall.  Is there a way to do that?

For a really quickly-made simplified example, I create a view something like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT (var1 * 2 - var2 * 3) AS result FROM
      (SELECT var1 FROM table1) AS var1,
      (SELECT var2 FROM table2) AS var2
    ORDER by result DESC
```

And that will return a list of values.

Like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT (var1 * 2 - var2 * 3) AS result, place FROM
      (SELECT var1 FROM table1) AS var1,
      (SELECT var2 FROM table2) AS var2
    ORDER by result DESC
```

But I don't know how to define "place".  Place is the place that result came in.  So whatever is in the 47th row, has "47" for a value in "place".

My eventual goal is to be able to get a list of all `place`s whose result value is a tie with another row.

Comment: This is too vague. Please provide a minimum reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve (sample data and expected results as tabular text), show us your current attempt and explain where you are currently stucked.

Comment: @GMB Updated my question with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a somewhat modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer), `row_number()` makes this easy:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view(result, place) AS
 SELECT result, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY result DESC)
 FROM (SELECT (table1.var1 * 2 - table2.var2 * 3) AS result
       FROM table1
       JOIN table2)
 ORDER BY result DESC;
```

(Note use of ANSI join syntax instead of that ancient comma stuff that is best avoided).

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f09c705a791eea0900534446ba3a77e1)

---

I do think as a general rule that the `ORDER BY` should be left out; whatever selects from the view should be responsible for ordering the data for presentation, not it - what if you sometimes want a different order? The good news in this case, though, is that the sort is essentially free since it needs to be done anyways to compute the row number.

Comment: Yep!  I just figured it out and was coming back here to post `row_number` as the solution and you beat me to it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT (t1.var1 * 2 - t2.var2 * 3) AS result, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (t1.var1 * 2 - t2.var2 * 3) DESC) as place
    FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
         table2 t2
    ORDER by result DESC;
```

In most databases, `ORDER BY` in a view is either a no-op or not allowed syntactically.  I think it is allowed in SQLite, however.

Note that if you want ties to have the same position, then use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` in sqlite is a directive to the query planner to never reorder the join. Usually not needed or wanted unless it can't work out the best order on its own for some reason. See https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#manual_control_of_query_plans_using_cross_join